# Browser Compatibilty for the asp Menu css not working in google chrome

Tags: asp.net, css

This is my menu used in my application this works in all the browsers except google chrome.

In google chrome I'm not able to get the sub menus. In IE on mouse over of the menu I will  get the sub menus.  This is the part I have used in the master page..

Thanks in advance....

The css is given below:

```
.DynamicMenu
{
    border-right: solid 1px #e1ebf7;
    border-top: solid 1px #e1ebf7;
    border-left: solid 1px #e1ebf7;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e1ebf7;
}

.DynamicMenuItem
{
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    background-color: #e1ebf7;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
}

.DynamicMenuItem A:link
{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}

.DynamicMenuHover
{
    background-color: #9cb7d8;
}

.DynamicMenuItem A:hover
{
    color: White;
    background-color: #9cb7d8;
}

.DynamicMenuSelected
{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    background: url(../../Images/heding1-bg.gif) repeat-x;
}

.DynamicMenuSelected A
{
        color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    background: url(../../Images/heding1-bg.gif) repeat-x;
}

.DynamicMenuSelected A:hover
{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    background: url(../../Images/heding1-bg.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

This is Html code....

```
<asp:Menu ID="IDMMenu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
    StaticDisplayLevels="1" StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/Images/menuArrow_down.gif">
    <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="TabMenu" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="StaticMenuSelected" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="StaticMenuItem" />
    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="StaticMenuHover" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuSelected" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="DynamicMenu" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuItem" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuHover" />
  </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Please look at the question preview before posting, since you would have seen a problem with your code formatting...

Comment: K thanks...Do you the answer?

Comment: It would be nice if you spoke English and not textspeek; I'll look at it. Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: I have posted the html code can you look on it...

Comment: Nope, I don't do ASP. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue where an ASP sub-menu was not displaying in IE10 or Chrome.  I fixed my issue by adding the following code to the Page_Load method:

```
if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0)
{
     Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear();
}
```